# How can I redirect requests to php file extensions to aspx 404

Tags: iis-7, http-status-code-404

Right now I'm migrating my websites to a new server with IIS7 but I'm having a problem with 404 error pages.

Right now www.example.com/missing and www.example.com/missing.aspx go to my 404.aspx page, but something like www.example.com/missing.php or www.example.com/missing.asdfasdf return an IIS7 404 error page.

I'd like to have my own 404 error page returned instead of the IIS7 error page, but I'm have no clue how to do it.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? Did my answer help?

Comment: @Kev - No, this setting was already present in the config file :(

Comment: can you paste in the relevant sections of your `web.config` file, both `<customErrors>` and `<httpErrors>`. Also are you running in classic or integrated pipeline mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the following to your `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" 
                   path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: We finally flipped the switch and pointed our DNS to the new server. This is key for anyone else having this problem. If you're on the server locally, the IIS7 error pages will always show up no matter what. But the same URL works as expected to the outside world. Thank you for the help Kev!